# Creating a text file in android

Tags: java, android

so i know there are alot of questions about creating a text file in android but i cant find any answers to my specific questions.

So the device I'm using is not an phone or a tablet, its a controller with android on it so the file directory is getting me confused. i want to create a new file either on the sd card or the device itself (it doesn't really matter as long as i can see it). firstly, the device doesn't have google docs or sheets or anything like that, will i need to install one of these apps on it for it to be able to read .txt files? or does android have some sort of internal software to do that?

Secondly, i've found alot of code on how to create a new file but most of it seems to gloss over how to get file directory, is there a specific way i can get the file directory?

This is what im using so far and im not getting any errors but its also not creating any files (or at-least none that i can see).

```
    public void WriteToText(){
        String FILENAME = "hello_file";
        String string = "hello world!";

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1, I think all devices have Html viewer which can view the text files. If you click a text file in a file manager app, it should prompt you with a list of apps that can view the text file.

2, Your code is correct, but it creates a file in the app's private file directory, which is not visible to all other apps, including file manager apps. This is because of Android security policy to prevent any app to steal information from other apps.

If you want to write a file which is visible to other apps like file manager, there are 2 ways.

1. in old api level (<29?) you can get the get external storage with

   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

you will need to request permission for it.

2. save the file in your app's private directory like what you have done, then create a chooser to share it out with correct mime type (txt/plain?), it will prompt you to select app that can view this mime type like what file manager does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'm using sdk 31 but i tried using the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to try and save it to my sd card. using this code: ```         File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, "my-file-name.txt");
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            stream.write("text-to-write".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        } ```  but i still cant find the file

Comment: Yes I said this is for old api level.  Level 31 should use second way.

Comment: how do i create a chooser?

Comment: You can look at Intent.createChooser()

Comment: Yoyo please put code in a code block of your own post. Nobody likes to read code from a comment. Do you? Remove that comment.